# Разные результаты при умножении больших чисел

Tags: c++, c

Почему получается разный результат:

```
__int64 f1()
{
    return 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
}

__int64 f2()
{
    __int64 value = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return value * 1000;
}

int main()
{
    __int64 value1 = f1(); //500654080
    __int64 value2 = f2(); //86400000000
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Целочисленный литерал вроде `1000`, `64` и т.п. имеет тип `int` и выражение с умножением этих чисел тоже имеет тип `int`. Итоговое значение не помещается в целовой тип (происходит переполнение, формально UB) и вы видите искаженные результаты. При сохранении промежуточного значения в более широкий тип, результат последующего умножения также будет иметь более широкий тип, который способен содержать итоговое произведение правильно.

Чтобы заработал первый вариант, достаточно добавить к одному из литералов суффикс `ll`, таким образом превратив литерал из типа `int` в тип `long long int`.

Comment: Добавить суффикс к одному из литералов не достаточно: `std::cout << 10000 * 10000 * 10000 * 10000LL << '\n';` приводит к ошибке компиляции (если компилятор настроен критически) или результату *-7273799680000* (если у компилятора хорошее настроение).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я считал, что это должно быть очевидным для цепочных операций. Если "переполнение" происходит на одном "звене", то последующие действия теряют смысл, конечно же.